# Some errors in my simple Xcode swift script: Found nil, and while performing a function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I have been working on an Xcode swift reflex test game app, which consists of a main screen with the game, which is working fine, and on a scoreboard. Before showing you my code, I believe the problem has to do with the fact that I have 2 views connected to 2 view controllers, lets say view 1 and view 2. One of the errors happened during the viewdidload function, where It reloads the value of a label to update the user's highscore, and that label is in screen 1. When the view initially loads, all is fine, but when the user clicks a button to go into the other view, it crashes, and it points to the function in view did load as a problem. I think it is because when it switches views, it tries to reload the label but the label is on the other view. In addition, I'm getting errors when I try to reload data in my table(which is on the other screen). Any help or advice would be great. Thanks! Here's the code!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
var arr = [Int]()
var timer = NSTimer()
var countdowntimer = NSTimer()
var count = 0
var countdown = Int(arc4random_uniform(4000) + 1000)
var highscore:Int!
var buttonTapCounter:Int!
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()


@IBOutlet weak var beginButton: UIButton!


@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var resetDataButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var averageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bestLabel: UILabel!





@IBOutlet weak var startButton: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var highScoreButton: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!

func updateTime() {
    countdown = countdown - 1
    if countdown <= 0 {
        startButton.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        startButton.text = "Tap Now!"
        countdowntimer.invalidate()
        backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "red")
        count = 0
        Timer()
    }
}

func Timer() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.001, target:self, selector:Selector("reflexTest"), userInfo:nil, repeats: true)

}

func reflexTest() {
    count = count + 1
    timerLabel.text = "\(count) ms"
}



@IBAction func returnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    buttonTapCounter = 0
}


@IBAction func scoreButtonTouched(sender: AnyObject) {
    buttonTapCounter = 0
    table.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func beginTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if startButton.text == "Tap when the Color Changes" {
        startButton.text = "You tapped too early!"
        countdowntimer.invalidate()
        countdown = Int(arc4random_uniform(4000) + 1000)
    } else {
        if count == 0 {
            countdowntimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.001, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            startButton.text = "Tap when the Color Changes"
            countdown = Int(arc4random_uniform(4000) + 1000)
            timerLabel.text = "\(count) ms"
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
            backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "green")
            startButton.text = "Tap to Begin"
            arr.append(count)
            count = 0
            highscore = minElement(arr)
            highScoreButton.text = "Best: \(highscore) ms"
            saveDefaults()

        }

    }

}

func loadDefaults() {

    if let savedArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("data") as? [Int] {
    self.arr = savedArray
    }
}
func saveDefaults() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.arr, forKey: "data")

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy HH:mm"
    let dateInFormat = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    var tableArray: [Int]! = arr
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(tableArray[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
func highScoreButtonText() {
    highScoreButton.text = "Best: \(highscore) ms"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadDefaults()



        highscore = minElement(arr)
       highScoreButtonText()




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information. Like what line is the that is crashes on? What button are they pressing? I think that button is in another view and you might want to include that.

Comment: Sorry, but I feel personally insulted, especially when you make comments like this. If you read what I said, I said that the button was in another view, that 2 views were on the same view controller. Please find the time to read my comment before commenting.